# Antlr4 - gated semantic predicates

Tags: antlr4, predicate

Since Antlr4 no longer supports gated semantic predicates, I came up with a workaround. However, if anyone has run into this, I would like to know if there are any caveats to doing something like this and also am I following best practices.

I'm following the standard 'C' if statement in the form of:
if (evaluation) {
     ...code block
}

Here is the code in the code block:

```
if ($result == false) { // If the statement evealuates to false
    // Consume tokens until the end of block marker
    while (getCurrentToken().getText().compareTo("}") != 0){
        consume();
    }

    // Set the parser state as if it had executed the tokens
    _localctx.start = getCurrentToken();
    _ctx.start = getCurrentToken();
    setState(220); 
    _errHandler.sync(this);
    consume(); // Consume the end of block marker

    return _localctx; // Exit the rule
}
```

I figure that Terrance Parr must have had a good reason to take out the support for a gated semantic predicate and this seems like a simple workaround. I'm just wondering if I'm missing something.

I tested it and it works, even with an 'else'. I have not tried it with compound evaluation statements (ie conditions separated with '&&' or '||'. I have a high confidence that it will work though.

Comment: Why do you need such a predicate? AFAIK, there should no longer be a need for such a thing. ANTLR4's normal predicate should suffice.

Comment: The issue comes when you want to add functionality to the language. With the normal predicate, even if the 'if' evaluates to false, Antlr4 tries to evaluate the code block. When I asked Terrance Parr about it, he referred me to a book on parsers, pretty much to tell me to write my own. i had another solution but it was kind of ugly. I optionally loaded an overlay but it caused a lot of problems when I went to write an IDE.